# C# SqlConnection child form closing, but data is not updated in MainForm

Tags: c#, parent-child, formclosing

My first question to this forum, so please be kind :D

I'm building a desktop application in C# that should read data from a Raspberry Pi and show it (values, charts...). The `MainForm.cs` has a menu strip where I can call a child form, `ConnectionSetupForm.cs` where I can enter the database connection values (db user, password, table, host, port, etc.) which are stored as `Properties.Settings.Default.xxx` (`System.Configuration`).

When I'm closing this child form with a save button, I want the `MainForm` to get this information and refresh. This works, but only after I restart the application, but it should be when the `FormClosing` or `FormClosed` event of the child form happens (in my example the `MessageBox.Show()` never occurs).

What am I missing? I have no errors and no warnings.

`MainForm` calls the child form `ConnectionSetupForm`:

```
private void showConnectionForm(object sender)
{
    connectionSetupForm = new ConnectionSetupForm();
    connectionSetupForm.MdiParent = this.ParentForm;
    connectionSetupForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
    connectionSetupForm.ShowDialog();

    connectionSetupForm.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(ConnectionForm_FormClosed);
}

private void ConnectionForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();   
    Properties.Settings.Default.Reload();
    MessageBox.Show("Closed");      // is never called, so this method is never called...

    // actually, I want to do some stuff here, e.g.:
    this.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.ApplicationName;    // name is changed after restart only
    connectionSetupForm = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks to be a simple mis-ordering of a couple lines. The `connectionSetupForm.ShowDialog();` line is actually a call to a blocking function. This means nothing past this line will execute until **AFTER** your dialog closes. Because you add the `FormClosed` event handler after the form has already closed, the `ConnectionForm_FormClosed()` function never gets called.

Try simply putting the `FormClosed` event handler before the `connectionSetupForm.ShowDialog();` line.

```
private void showConnectionForm(object sender)
{
    connectionSetupForm = new ConnectionSetupForm();
    connectionSetupForm.MdiParent = this.ParentForm;
    connectionSetupForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
    connectionSetupForm.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(ConnectionForm_FormClosed);
    connectionSetupForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It was the solution. Just by looking at the code I couldn't see it. Now it's working as expected.